# How to use the "Parameter Field" in "SQL Expression Field" in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: sql, jsp, crystal-reports

I am working on a JSP application, where I have to generate reports.

A report is generated based on the record which the user chooses in the webpage. So, I am passing the primary key value, from my JSP page to the Crystal Reports using `viewer.setParameterFields` method.

In Crystal reports designer, I need to use this id in a SQL statement to retrieve that particular record.

How can I achieve this? I tried creating a parameter field, but I don't know how to use it in SQL query, and basically how to link the JSP and Crystal Reports.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parameter field in a SQL-expression field.

You can, however, use a parameter field with a Command object (assuming that the parameter was defined in the Command object).

Comment: Thanks, but how to I access the Parameter Field from Command Object?

Comment: Assuming you are in the Command-object editor, you can either double click the parameter in the list or just type it.  Format {?param_name}.